# Ensure that a condition is always true in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, assert

In JavaScript, is it possible to test whether a condition remains true throughout a program's entire execution? Here, I want to ensure that the variable a is always divisible by 3, from the start of the program to the end.

```
//Assert that the following is always true, and print an error message if not true
ensureAlwaysTrue(a % 3 == 0); //print an error message if a is not divisible by 0
                              //from this point onward

a = 6;

a = 10 //print error message, since a % 3 != 0

function ensureAlwaysTrue(){
    //this is the function that I'm trying to implement.
}
```

One solution would be add statements to check the assertions after every single variable assignment, but that would be redundant and cumbersome. Is there a more concise way to check whether a condition is true throughout a program's execution?

Comment: For testing/verification, I'd strongly recommend detailed unit tests focusing on method entry/exit points rather than the state of a variable after every statement - much simpler to create, more maintainable throughout code updates, and much better performance in the production code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the idea from @Chris (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14534019/1394841), you could enclose your whole code in a string, and then do something like:

```
function ensureAlwaysTrue(condition, code)
{
    var statements = code.split(";");
    for (var i = 0; i < statements.length-1; i++) { //last statement is empty
        eval(statements[i] + ";");
        if (!condition()) error();
        //break; //if desired
    }
}

var code =
"a = 6;\
a = 10; //print error message, since a % 3 != 0\
";

ensureAlwaysTrue(function(){return (a % 3 == 0);}, code);
```

Comment: I know it's ugly, but it works: "> function error() { console.log("error! a: " + a); }" -> "> ensureAlwaysTrue(function(){return (a % 3 == 0);}, code);" -> error! a: 10

Comment: Technically this would work in the very simple example given, but it's a bit sketchy and dangerous - you'd want to have a more advanced statement parser (this will fail on the first `if` statement or `for` loop).  `eval` code is also very difficult to debug, which is likely more useful in the long run.

Comment: @Chris, yeah, it would definitively break on the first `for` statement or an `if` without braces... just a silly hack though.

Comment: There was a syntax error in the original, since `error` was not defined. Here's a version with correct syntax: http://jsfiddle.net/jarble/DJagG/2/

Comment: This seems to work well, but I think it would be better to insert the function-checking statement between each line in a function, and then evaluate the modified function.

Comment: Here's an updated version (still buggy, and a work-in-progress): http://jsfiddle.net/jarble/DJagG/5/

Comment: Nice to see you're still working at it... but as Chris pointed out, it'll break horribly if you try something just a little bit more complicated like a for loop. I'd rather go with "THEtheChad"'s alternative to use a custom function instead ;)

Answer (score 3):

Wow, these are all horrible solutions. If you really want to do this, you make a model and access the value using methods on the model. Here's an example:

```
function Model(value){
  this.value = value;
}

Model.prototype = {
  get: function(){
    return this.value;
  },

  set: function(value){
    if(this.validate(value)){
      this.value = value;
      return this;
    }
    throw Error('Not a valid value.');
  },

  test: function(func){
    this.validate = func;
    return this;
  }
};

var a = new Model();

a.test(function(val){ return val == 7 });

// Sets value of a to 7
a.set(7);
// Gets value of a (7 in this case)
a.get();
// Throws an error
a.set(5);
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

The closest you may get in Javascript would be finding some tool that "compiles" your code to automatically inject the `ensure` function call after every statement, like [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) for Java.

A potential way to do it in another language may be with a background thread; Javascript threads (web workers) will not be able to access the variables in the other threads.  Javascript is also an interpreted language that will just run code sequentially - unless the `ensure` function is actually there in the execution path, it will not execute.

Comment: AspectJ looks interesting. Is it possible to ensure that a condition in Java is always true using AspectJ?

Comment: I've only used it for injecting testing/logging code on method entry/exit, but it has more control available I haven't looked into.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could add a timed interval, like

```
assertInterval = 10; //milisseconds

function ensureAlwaysTrue(condition)
{
    setInterval(function(){ if(!condition()) error(); }, assertInterval);
}
```

And you would call it like:

```
var a = 6;

ensureAlwaysTrue(function(){return (a % 3 == 0);});
```

That would catch it, but with a maximum of `assertInterval` milisseconds delay.

**Edit:**
It actually won't work, as @Chris pointed out: "your interval function won't actually run between statements in the currently executing function".
It's true, it would only work for asserting between events or such.

Comment: Would there be any way to add a delay after a statement in JavaScript?

Comment: This won't work, since your interval function won't actually run between statements in the currently executing function, and will only run when the stack unwinds...

Comment: See [John Resig's article on Javascript Timers](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) to understand why this answer is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, and for the link to the article too!